# Holonomic constraints and variables

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

Let's consider a holonomic constraint:

$$f(q_{1},...,q_{n},t)=0$$

Must every term that compares in the equation be writable as a combination of the variables of a function?

For example, in the holonomic constraint for the pendulum:
$x^{2}+y^{2}-L^{2}=0$ , i can write $L$ as a function of $x$ and $y$.

Moreover, the math behind this formula wants that every variable $v\in \left \{ q_{1},...,q_{n},t \right \}$ must compare in the equation?

Comment: Are you asking if the constraint can be written as a [graph of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function)?

Comment: „I can write L as a function of x and y“?. No you can write x as function of L and y, or y as function of L and x